# How to prevent webpack to create js file for css?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

```
const path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CssEntryPlugin = require("css-entry-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './js/index.js',
        product_details: './js/index.js',
        signup: ['./js/signup.js','./js/index.js'],
        signup_style: ['./css/signup.css']
   },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: "[name].min.js"
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
          { 
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [{
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                        }
                    }]
            })
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/[name].css')
      ]
};
```

Above is my webpack.config.js file. It creates **signup_style.min.js** and **signup_style.css** files. I want only **signup_style.css** file to 
create and not **signup_style.min.js**.

How can we do that?

Comment: updpate `test: /\.js/,` to `test: /\.js$/,`

Answer (score 18):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fix-style-only-entries

> This is a small plugin developed to solve the problem of having a style only entry (css/sass/less) generating an extra js file.

Comment: Didn't work for me + introduced a bunch of deprecation warnings into the build output.

Comment: Works flawlessly for me. No deprecation warnings.

Comment: throwing deprecated warning for Webpack 5.75

Answer (score 3):

By default webpack will generate that .min.js file. As in your configuration `output` all the entry files `must generate` its js files.

> Note: **extract-text-webpack-plugin** will extract all css/sass located in your js entry files.
>
> It moves all the required *.css modules in entry chunks into a separate CSS file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the JS bundle, but in a separate CSS file (styles.css).

All you need to do is to remove that file if you don't want it.
I am using https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin/. Where you can define what files you will remove before or after webpack bundling.

Comment: More native way is to move request for your css file from entry point to index file (or any js file) with "require" keyword.  Also it won't force you to remove js file for css. "Dummy" code for css will be included in your js bundle.

Comment: I don't want to import css in any js file. I want separate CSS and JS files

Comment: @Trupti But you mentioned you don't want .min.js files if so you just remove it using filemanager-webpack-plugin.

Comment: For css file, it creates js and css file...instead of that I just want css file only and not js.

Comment: When you define it to entry property webpack will generate a js file for it and ExtractTextPlugin will extract all css from that generated webpack js files. I would also like to  clarify why do you need to generate css when you have `signup.css` already?