# Webpack generates js files with css / scss files

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, mini-css-extract-plugin

## Description

In webpack I am using **mini-css-extract-plugin**:

```
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[hash].css',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].css',
  })
]
```

To load scss files in **chunk files**:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, options: {
        hmr: isdev,
        reloadAll: true
      }
    },
    "css-loader",
    "sass-loader",
  ]
}
```

When I load a scss with an **dynamic import**:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "test" */ 'test.scss')
```

It will generate a **test.[hash].css** containing the styles and a **test.[hash].js**:

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([[15],{

/***/ 81:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin

/***/ })

}]);
```

## Problem

I want to minimize the delay and loaded files so I find it redundant to have a nearly empty **test.[hash].js** file.

Do you have a way to either include the scss in the js file (see Idea 1) or to not emit/use the nearly empty js file?

### Idea 1: not using mini-css-extract-plugin

My first idea was not using mini-css-extract-plugin for dynamic imported scss, but this will include a lot css-base stuff in the js (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/255).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent webpack to create js file for css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983748/how-to-prevent-webpack-to-create-js-file-for-css)

Comment: Unfortunatly webpack-fix-style-only-entries did not work, I added a new issue here: https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries/issues/19

Comment: I've found an updated plugin which works: https://libraries.io/npm/webpack-remove-empty-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extract of code that could interrest you. It's coded in live here, so there is maybe some error I don't know.

I use an alternative way but nearby inside my own project.

The behaviour is :

1. Use the Event Hook Plugin and call it when the webpack is done
2. Loop through each file
3. If file is css and have the same name as with js extension
4. Then remove the js file

   ```
   const EventHooksPlugin = require('event-hooks-webpack-plugin');
   const path             = require('path');
   const fs               = require('fs');
   const _                = require('underscore');

   plugins: [
       new EventHooksPlugin({
               done: () => {
                       const publicDir = __dirname + '/public';
                       const files     = fs.readdirSync(publicDir);

                       _.each(files, file => {
                             if (path.extname(file) !== '.css') { return ;}

                             const fileJs = file.replace('.css', '.js');

                             if (!fs.existsSync(fileJs)) {return;}

                             fs.unlinkSync(fileJs);
                       });
               }
       })
   ]
   ```